# Protect API with CSRF token or other authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

In a Rails project I am setting up my own API, which I would like to call from the same site with some jQuery calls.

For example, I have a route `POST /api/v1/employee`.

I want this API call to be available for users of my site, but also for an external client that is calling this API with (for example) basic authentication.

So I would like to protect my API against CSRF when the call is coming from my own site and when it is from an external client I want it to check for the username and password in the header of the request.

I set up jQuery to add the csrf token specified in the meta tags of my page, to the every request it does to the API.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
      }
});
```

But now I am not sure where to go from here.

In my controller I added the following line that enabled my client to connect to the API without problems, but then I have no protection.

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```

If I set up a `before_filter` for this controller it *always* checks for the username and password, even when a csrf token is available.

`before_filter :authentication_check`

^ authentication_check is a method I created which does a simple basic authentication check (just to get this going).

I also tried to do the following:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception, :unless => :valid_user?
```

But this probably doesn't do what I think. `valid_user?` is a method that checks the basic authentication and returns the user if correct.

I somehow want to combine these 2 things. If there is no session (so it's and external client connecting) I want to authenticate on username/password and otherwise just use the normal CSRF protection.

**UPDATE November 25th 2015**

Ok I now have the following solution for `POST` requests. Still need to add `GET`, etc, but here it is.

In my controller I have this:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception, unless: :valid_apikey
```

My `:valid_apikey` thing method is defined like this:

```
def valid_apikey

    result = authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
        !User.find_by_token(token).nil?
    end
    result == true

end
```

So, if I am correct, the CSRF checking is skipped when the request supplies a token that is in my database. When the token is not in my database the `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` method returns an `Array` (which is different than `true`).

Comment: You could have two controllers: one for your internal use (with CSRF protection only), the other - dedicated api endpoint (with api key protection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got this solved for I think. I also want my GET requests to check for the CSRF token.

In my controller I do the following:

```
def verified_request?
    if !request.headers["X-API-KEY"].nil?
        !ApiClient.find_by_token(request.headers["X-API-KEY"]).nil?
    else
        !protect_against_forgery? ||
            valid_authenticity_token?(session, params[request_forgery_protection_token]) ||
            valid_authenticity_token?(session, request.headers['X-CSRF-Token'])
    end
end
```

This overrides the `verified_request?` method of the inherited ApplicationController. I can't just call `super`, because then my `GET` requests will not get checked.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you dont have to put an exception for your `protect_from_forgery`

You can simply do this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def handle_unverified_request
    # your logic to handle request coming from outside your domain
    # if user is not valid then
    raise(ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)
    # else allow to bypass
  end
```

This way u can control and also for normal requests from your domain, you dont ve to go through if conditions and hitting db everytime.

Comment: Thanks, that got me on track. I also want to grab GET (and other) requests, so I am handling it in `verified_request?`.